# Extracting a small subset of an .sdc file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, feature-class, feature-dataset, smart-data-compression

There are some line features in the form of an .sdc file. I do not need all the data in the file, just a very small subset of it. I understand that .sdc files are highly compressed, and my file is **very** large and will take up a lot of space when extracted. My question is, how do I go about turning a small subset of the file into a feature class in a feature dataset?

Do I extract the data first, and then run the Clip tool on the result (which would probably be very time- and computationally intensive), or is there some different procedure with .sdc files?

Comment: "Highly compressed" probably overstates the case.  Since ArcGIS reads .sdc, have you tried just making a selection and exporting to the target format?

Comment: The SDC workspace factory is not implemented for export. You can extract a sample as a shapefile or geodatabase feature class but if you want a SDC feature class be prepared to write some ArcObjects.

Comment: I want the SDC feature class as the input, not an output, for the Clip tool. Can the tool be run directly on the SDC feature class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware of the licensing restrictions on using the SDC datasets. If you work with an Esri Street Map Premium or other commercial product delivered in SDC format, there is a chance the extraction tool will be locked for the key dataset (such as streets).

If it's just some legacy system with an SDC feature class, you should be able to convert the SDC into a gdb feature class by using [Feature Class To Geodatabase](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//001200000021000000) GP tool as outlined [here](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/35632). You can also just right-click the SDC feature class and choose Export.

I still have some GP workflows based on using the SDC feature class, and they can be used as input datasets into GP tools that don't modify them, i.e. Clip is perfectly OK (but not the Calculate Field). So, you can use the SDC feature class as an input for the Clip tool, but the output will be a shapefile or a gdb feature class.

Comment: The dataset was downloaded here: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f38b87cc295541fb88513d1ed7cec9fd, so I doubt that there should be any licensing restrictions (correct me if I'm wrong). As for the geometry fields, shouldn't those be calculated automatically when the output of the Clip tool is imported into a geodatabase?

Comment: "but the Calculate Field".... Does that mean the geometry fields? But shouldn't those be calculated automatically once I import the output of the Clip tool into a feature dataset?

Comment: This, then, is what I'm doing:  1. Clipping the SDC feature class directly;  2. Importing the resulting shapefile into my feature dataset.  Let me know if there is anything wrong with this course of action.

Comment: @Hattifnatt, you got it right. Sorry for the typo on the Calculate Field. This tool is just one of those tool that I referred to tell you that there are some tools that modify the input data without creating any new output datasets. Since the SDC are just read-only, you wouldn't be able to calculate fields. This has nothing to do with the geometry. Your workflow will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workflow to get around geoprocessing tool limitatoins with .sdc files: http://www.geomattix.com/blog/clip-esri-streetmap-data-to-your-study-area/

Answer (score 0):

I did not encounter any issues with geoprocessing tools being locked. Simply clipping and exporting to a geodatabase worked.